# How to match all spellings of the word except one?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Let's say I would like to match all spellings of the word `abc` except one - `abc`. So in a text of:
`abc word abC 3226 aBc aBC Abc AbC ABc ABC` it would match all these abc's except for the first one - `abc` and not other characters in the text. Can't think of how to write this.

I tried `(?i)(abc)(?!abc)`, `(?i)(abc)^(?!abc)`, `^(?!abc)(?i)(abc)`, `^(?!abc)(?i:abc)`, `\b(?!abc)(?i:abc)\b` in notepad++, none of these work on the text above:

[image]

Comment: I tried negative lookahead (?i)ABC^(?!abc), it doesn't work.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to get started with regex.

Comment: Please add the pattern to the question. You need to use it before the pattern. Something like `\b(?!abc)(?i:abc)\b`. However, it is not clear if it is a "word", or "string". Maybe  `^(?!abc)(?i:abc)$` will work better for you.

Comment: Nice instadownvote and instaclose, I'll have to create a new one from scratch.

Comment: Do not create a new one, just edit this one and state what problem you have with your current pattern.

Comment: I edited it. Neither of regular expressions you suggested work on the string in question:  https://i.imgur.com/oFAAJ5c.png. But what good will it do that I edited the question with the ones I tried, you closed the question, so people can't answer.

Comment: But you did not check "Match Case". Your regex is case insensitive and there is no sense using `(?i)` inside it, since it is enabled already. Check *Match Case* option and use `\b(?!abc)(?i:abc)\b` or `\b(?!abc)(?i)abc\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not check **Match Case** option and that made your regex match in a case insensitive way.

Check **Match Case** option and use

```
\b(?!abc)(?i:abc)\b
```

Or,

```
\b(?!abc)(?i)abc\b
```

Or, do not bother with NPP settings and use a second inline modifier or modifier group to override case insensitive options:

```
\b(?!(?-i)abc)(?i)abc\b
\b(?!(?-i:abc))(?i:abc)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fIXDoS/1)

So, `(?i)` turns on case insensitivity (`(?i:...)` does it for a group), and `(?-i)` turns the case insensitivity off (`(?-i:...)` does it for a group).

Comment: Thanks. Well, I never got regular expressions. I read quite a few articles(on regular-expressions.info and sites like that one) to write different regular expressions but I don't work with them often, so information I read gets erased with time. I'd totally pick a course and a book to properly learn them to properly understand them and write them, but because I won't apply them after even if I read a book, it'll get erased after about 12-24 months of not using them at all or using them around 10 times during that period of time.